# Merge tags on serverfault [nameserver] and [nameservers]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

No reason for these to be separate.

Comment: But which one is to be left?

Comment: does it matter?  keep singular it has more tags

Comment: It does matter and you don't even bother to note the tag counts.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Any chance of making it so Community doesn't bump 2 year old questions tagged [status-*]?

Answer (score 1):

This is complete, and a synonym is in place.